# Using foldr for search instead of foldl in haskell

Tags: haskell

So I'm reading ["*Learn You A Haskell*"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and in the [chapter about modules](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#data-list), there's a definition of a function named search, which checks whether a list contains a sub-list.

```
my_search :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
my_search sub l = 
  let 
    len = length sub
    eqTest = (\acc x -> if take len x == sub then True else acc) 
  in foldl eqTest False $ tails l
```

Now, I wonder why not use `foldl'` which was mentioned earlier in this chapter, and runs faster:

```
my_search' :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
my_search' sub l = 
  let 
    len = length sub
    eqTest = (\acc x -> if take len x == sub then True else acc) 
  in foldl' eqTest False $ tails l


*Main> my_search [10^6,10^6+1] [1..10^7]
True
(7.76 secs, 3,197,168,792 bytes)

*Main> my_search' [10^6,10^6+1] [1..10^7]
True
(4.53 secs, 2,964,986,352 bytes)
```

Better yet, with a small adjustment, we can use `foldr` which can also handle infinite lists by short-circuiting.

```
my_searchr :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
my_searchr sub l = 
  let 
    len = length sub
    eqTest = (\x acc -> if take len x == sub then True else acc) 
  in foldr eqTest False $ tails l
```

Looking at the [definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/Data-List.html#%5C) of `isInfixOf`, I see it's implemented with `any`, which uses `foldr`.

Am I missing something or is it better to use `foldr` in this case?

Comment: it's probably because the authors did not care about performance but about the modules here(?) ...

Comment: Some more details about the difference between the various folds: https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'

Comment: @ErikR. Thanks, I've read the wiki, and AFAIU, `foldl` is almost never used.

Comment: `foldl` is indeed rarely used, since it has an inherent low performance on long lists. In the LYAH example, I don't like the `if` part. I'd use `(take len x == sub) || acc`. When folding left, I would also flip that to `acc || ...` to speed up a little (when folding right instead this would speed everything down). Further, there's `isPrefixOf` which could have been used or reimplementedas an exercise here ...

Comment: @chi there are sadly no exercises in LYAH (last I checked)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I missing something or is it better to use foldr in this case?

No, you are not missing anything, and your analysis is right; `foldl` is not the right tool here, and even `foldl'` is dubious; the task at hand inherently benefits from laziness, so `foldr` should be used.

Comment: Thanks, in " so foldl should be used.", did you mean `foldr`?